# definition of intervals for proof

Tags: real-analysis

proof: every closed $[a,b]$ interval contains infinitely many rationals

let $[0,1] = \{x \in \mathbb{Z} | 0 \leq x \leq 1 \}$

then every closed interval doesn't contain infinitely many rationals, but

is this an interval, or does an interval have to be that of reals, such as,

$[a,b] = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | a \leq x \leq b \}$

Comment: Well, the closed interval $\;[\pi,\pi]=\{\pi\}\;$ contains no rational at all...

Comment: @DonAntonio ok, but can an interval be a set of integers, or does it have to be a set of reals?

Comment: In the context of pretty much any calculus, measure theory, topology, or analysis question, an interval always refers to an interval of the reals. Additionally, you probably need the hypothesis that $a\neq b$ as already stated by @DonAntonio

Comment: @hit In real analysis, it is **always**, as far as I am aware of, defined as a subset of the real line. If one wants integers or rationals then such an interval can be intersected with $\;\Bbb Z,\,\Bbb Q\;$ .

Comment: In a totally ordered set $A$ a closed interval is the subset $\{x\in A:\ a\leq x\leq b\}$ for some elements $a,b\in A$. So, your first example is an interval on the integers, the second an interval on the reals.

Comment: @hit As an addendum, you do not get to define what the symbols $[a,b]$ mean, so you cannot just willy-nilly declare that $[0,1]=\{0,1\}$. Those symbols have ostensibly been defined in your text.

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of this problem, an "interval" is an interval in the ordered set $\mathbb{R}$, so $[a,b]=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a\leq x\leq b\}$.  In general (and especially in real analysis), this is usually the default meaning of "interval" unless the context indicates otherwise.  You can speak of intervals in any ordered set using the same notation $[a,b]$ and sometimes you do, but if nothing specifically indicates what ordered set you are talking about then it is usually meant to be $\mathbb{R}$.